# Can't select .NET Core as framework for Service Fabric Application

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

When I create a new Service Fabric Application in Visual Studio 2019 (i.e. the project containing the .sfproj file, not an individual service), I can't select .NET Core as the framework for the project. I only get to choose between different versions of .NET Framework. Is this expected or does it have anything to do with my setup? I've migrated all the other projects in the service fabric solution to .NET Core, but I can't migrate the .sfproj project. Although not a huge problem, it would be nice to get rid of .NET Framework entirely.

Steps to reproduce: File > New > Project > Search for and select "Service Fabric Application" > Next

[image: Creating the service fabric application]

Comment: Do you have .net core available as an option for other templates?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Yes, I can for instance create an `ASP.NET Core Web Application` with .NET Core

Comment: I just tried on my machine. Select the latest .Net version then press 'Create'. On the next screen you can select 'core' options. Sorry I can't provide an explanation or confirm whether that's the right approach.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ I think that's where it asks you to create a Service Fabric service, so it won't affect the project that contains the .sfproj

Comment: @ShamPooSham you should confirm JayMee's comment as the answer and up vote

Comment: @Mahan.A JayMee's comment doesn't change the fact that the application project (sfproj) uses .NET Framework. My question is about getting the application project to use .NET Core.

Comment: Has anyone had luck updating the sfproj to .NET 6? Now that we're looking to upgrade from 6 to 8, it would be nice if our sfproj weren't stuck on framework 4.8

Answer (score 0):

As JayMee points out in the comments, the first selection is for the fabric *application* and the subsequent selection is for the fabric *service*. These create two projects in your solution, using `sfproj` and `csproj` files, respectively. I chose .NET Framework 4.8 for my app and .NET Core 3.1 for my service.

Note that even though it's called a "service", it is also an application, complete with `Program.cs`, hence `netcoreapp3.1` instead of something like `netstandard` for a library (this surprised me).

Note also that currently (VS 16.11.2) the app project `sfproj` file it creates is an old Framework style project file, not a new SDK style project file.

Comment: I think I've made it clear in my question that I want the SF Application, not the SF Service, to use .NET Core. I have already migrated the SF Services to .NET Core